# Why return is only returning the first one?

Tags: php

When I do the following:

```
  if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='it'){
    $it1 = "<li><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time' aria-hidden='true'></span> Il periodo antico</strong> è dal <strong>3500 a.C. fino al 476 d.C.</strong></li>";
    $it2 = "<li><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time' aria-hidden='true'></span> Il periodo medievale</strong> è dal <strong>476 dC fino al 1492 d.C.</strong></li>";
    $it3 = "<li><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time' aria-hidden='true'></span> Il periodo moderno</strong> è dal <strong>1492 dC fino al 1789 d.C.</strong></li>";
    $it4 = "<li><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time' aria-hidden='true'></span> Il periodo Contemporaneo</strong> va dal <strong>1789 d.C. fino ad oggi.</strong></li>";
    return $it1; 
    return $it2; 
    return $it3; 
    return $it4;
  }
```

Only the first one is returned:

```
<li><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time' aria-hidden='true'></span> Il periodo antico</strong> è dal <strong>3500 a.C. fino al 476 d.C.</strong></li>
```

I tried to use `echo` instead of `return` and it works but it places it outside the layout therefore i really need to use `return` but I don't understand why only one is returned.

Comment: It's returning only first one because you are returning from first one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`return`  function means stop executing code further.

Any function can not have more than 1 return. whenever the function is getting first return it stopping immediately and returning the first one.

You should try this

```
if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='it'){
    $it1 = "<li><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time' aria-hidden='true'></span> Il periodo antico</strong> è dal <strong>3500 a.C. fino al 476 d.C.</strong></li>";
    $it1 .= "<li><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time' aria-hidden='true'></span> Il periodo medievale</strong> è dal <strong>476 dC fino al 1492 d.C.</strong></li>";
    $it1 .= "<li><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time' aria-hidden='true'></span> Il periodo moderno</strong> è dal <strong>1492 dC fino al 1789 d.C.</strong></li>";
    $it1 .= "<li><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time' aria-hidden='true'></span> Il periodo Contemporaneo</strong> va dal <strong>1789 d.C. fino ad oggi.</strong></li>";
    return $it1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are returning, it stops execution whatever follows, and returns the variable/content you've told it to. The solution is to return the entire string at once, or if you need it separately, return an array.

```
if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='it'){
    $it1 = "<li><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time' aria-hidden='true'></span> Il periodo antico</strong> è dal <strong>3500 a.C. fino al 476 d.C.</strong></li>";
    $it1 .= "<li><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time' aria-hidden='true'></span> Il periodo medievale</strong> è dal <strong>476 dC fino al 1492 d.C.</strong></li>";
    $it1 .= "<li><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time' aria-hidden='true'></span> Il periodo moderno</strong> è dal <strong>1492 dC fino al 1789 d.C.</strong></li>";
    $it1 .= "<li><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time' aria-hidden='true'></span> Il periodo Contemporaneo</strong> va dal <strong>1789 d.C. fino ad oggi.</strong></li>";
    return $it1;
}
```

The above would return a string containing everything. You could return them as an array, which could be used as separate lines (depends on how you want to use this code).

```
if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='it'){
    $it1 = "<li><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time' aria-hidden='true'></span> Il periodo antico</strong> è dal <strong>3500 a.C. fino al 476 d.C.</strong></li>";
    $it2 = "<li><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time' aria-hidden='true'></span> Il periodo medievale</strong> è dal <strong>476 dC fino al 1492 d.C.</strong></li>";
    $it3 = "<li><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time' aria-hidden='true'></span> Il periodo moderno</strong> è dal <strong>1492 dC fino al 1789 d.C.</strong></li>";
    $it4 = "<li><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time' aria-hidden='true'></span> Il periodo Contemporaneo</strong> va dal <strong>1789 d.C. fino ad oggi.</strong></li>";
    return array($it1, $it2, it3, it4); 
}
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Answer (score 1):

That's happening because after `return`-ing `$it1` the function is done, no further code in it gets executed and the control is back to the place where it was called from.

If you need to get back all the `$it`-s you could return an array of them, smth like this:

```
return array($it1, $it2, $it3, $it4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Return is a keyword ending the function you are currently in. 
The drawback of soft-typed language like PHP is that it is possible to forget this fact.

(Did you misunderstood it as a 'yield' ? )

Echo is not displaying properly surely because of the function context. 
You could return a single array containing all the values you want and then display them in the upper function.

```
$arr = [val1, val2, val3, ... ]
return $arr
```

Answer (score 1):

In any language, `return` means the function stops execution afterward. In some languages, you can't put anything after the `return` statement. if you need to return more than one value from your method, you can do any of the following. As it's **PHP**, I'm going to give you some examples with PHP

```
function passByReference($param1, &$referencedParam1){
    // your code here,
    // change the referenced value here
    $referencedParam1 = $newValue;
    return $anotherCalculatedValue;
}
```

[image: function pass by reference]

```
function returnArray($param1, $param2, $param3){
    // your code here
    // return an array instead of a particular value
    return [$param1, $param2, $param3];
}

var_dump(returnArray(1,2,3));
var_dump(implode(", ", returnArray(1,2,3)));
```

[image: return array from a method]

I'd rather return an array, instead of string concatenation. You can use it however you like, but returning a concatenated string will stop you using that from anywhere if you want to use it in any other form.